# Google +1 and multilanguage website

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I want to add "Google +1" button to my website. I add elements

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Other">

<meta itemprop="name" content="title">
<meta itemprop="description" content="erterter">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.mmaer.com">
```

to my page. It works fine on single-language page, but works incorrectly in multilanguage case. My page defines language of page by language of browser and description fills depend on this language. So, even I see code of page:

```
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Magic Screenshot">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Russian text">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.magicscreenshot.com/Content/Images/error_FileNotFound_small.jpg">
```

when I click on "Google +1" I see english text. How to fix it?

I'm adding this button by following code

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300" data-href="http://wwww.com"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.___gcfg = { lang: 'ru' };

        (function () {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC 4 if it have any meaning

Comment: not sure what do you mean. If user opens page with russian language in the browser by default - it opens page with russian text, if with english lang - it opens page with english text. But user always get english text on his Google Plus page...

Comment: You say you are generating this <meta> tag based on the browser language. How? - meta tag is being generated by server code. I even don't understand sense of string window.___gcfg = { lang: 'ru' }; because even with this parameter user get english text on his google plus page.

Comment: Ok, I think these details deserve to be on the Question. Closing my participation, good luck!